# Почему результат функции не выводится в консоль? (JS)

Tags: javascript

Почему консоль молчит? Не получается оформить вывод функции. Должна появляться сумма квадратов элементов массива, с 2мя условиями (квадрат элемента больше 30 и элемент кратен 2м или 5ти).

```js
function getSum(array) {
  var sum = 0;
  var i = array.length;
  while (i) {
    var value = array[i] * array[i];
    if (value > 30 && (array[i] % 2 == 0 || array[i] % 5 == 0)) {
      sum += value;
    }
  }
  return sum;
}

var someArray = [1, 12, 10, 6, 15];

console.log(sum);

console.log(getSum(someArray));
```

Comment: вы похоже запутались в переменных своих. внимательно прочитайте код, который вне функции. и обратите внимание на область видимости

Comment: вообще если подождете, то браузер, наверное, скажет, что скрипт завис. но даже выполняя код в сниппете, видно что консоль "не молчит"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас ошибка в логике - `i = array.length; while(i)`, пока 5. Тут происходит приведение к boolean, 5 становится true, цикл будет идти. Если дадите на вход 0, то будет false и цикл не будет идти. Немного неправильная логика
Для цикла while следует проверять на то, что `i < array.length`, перед этим сделав i = 0 и после каждого шага цикла увеличивать i на единицу

С циклом for

```js
function getSum(array) {
  var sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var value = array[i] * array[i];
    if (value > 30 && (array[i] % 2 == 0 || array[i] % 5 == 0)) {
      sum += value;
    }
  }
  return sum;
}

var someArray = [1, 12, 10, 6, 15];

console.log(getSum(someArray));
```

c циклом while

```js
function getSum(array) {
  var sum = 0;
  var i = 0;
  while (i < array.length) {
    var value = array[i] * array[i];
    if (value > 30 && (array[i] % 2 == 0 || array[i] % 5 == 0)) {
      sum += value;
    }
    i++;
  }
  return sum;
}

var someArray = [1, 12, 10, 6, 15];

console.log(getSum(someArray));
```